# When is the zero flag set?

Tags: assembly, flags, status, microchip

I'm doing some studying for my exam in computer engineering in mid august. Some of the exercises are about counting the working register and status register for certain instructions in assembler. I'm struggling to understand how the status register and in particular the zero flag works in this exercise. The exercise is about calculating what the value of WREG is after these 11 instructions. I have written my answers on every line but somehow I don't get the status register and zero flag right:

1. `CLRF    WREG;`           WREG = 0x00
2. `BSF     STATUS,C;`       Carry flag = 1
3. `BSF     WREG,7;`         WREG = 0x80  (1000 0000) 7th bit set to 1.
4. `RLCF    WREG;`           W = 0x01 and status register 0x03?
5. `BC      MCARRY;`         We will branch because C is set.
6. `ADDLW   0x01;`           Therefore this line is skipped.
7. `MCARRY    DECF    WREG;`           W = 0x00
8. `MOVLW   OxFF;`           W = 0xFF, status register is somehow 7 here
9. `BZ      MHALT;`          Z bit is set since line 4.
10. `INCF    WREG;`          Therefore this line i skipped

11.`MHALT    GOTO    MHALT;`

WREG = 0xFF which is the right answer, but I don't understand what happens with the status register at line 4. Somehow it rotates together with WREG and the value gets put in the status register. And then later the value of the status register is 7 (line 8), which I am so confused about. Do any of u have a good explanation that can make me understand what happens with the status register and in particular the zero flag when executing instructions in assembler?

END

Comment: If Status = 0x030 the C and DC Bit are set not the Z Bit.

Comment: Use a simulator and go step by step through your sample code.

Comment: For the next time: use four blanks in front of every line of code to format code blocks.  You can highlight the code and then press the `{}` button to do this automatically.  Do not insert line numbers please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you have problem with. First you mention line 4. As you have correctly commented there, the MSB of WREG is 1, and that gets rotated into C. The original value of C which is also 1 gets rotated into the LSB of WREG. Thus WREG=0x01, C=1 and Z=0. Line 7 will set WREG=0x00, C=1 and Z=1. The `MOVW` does not affect flags so line 9 will use the value from line 7 not line 4.

Note that the status register is `0 0 0 N OV Z DC C`.

Comment: I think I understand now. The only time the zero flag gets set is when an operation performed on WREG (atleast in my case) results in WREG being 0.

Comment: When i debug the code in assembler, status register = 0x04 means that the Zero flag is set right?

Answer (score 0):

> WREG = 0x80    C = 1

rotate left through carry. The Carry is shifted into the LSBit of WREG and the MSBit of WREG is shifted into the Carry :

> WREG = 0x01     C = 1

Answer (score 0):

The zero flag is set when any assembler operation (in my case the WREG) results in the content of WREG being 0.